# selecting class from angular scss file

Tags: angular, sass

I am trying to select a class that is generated from a third party component.

```
<div role="tablist" class="mat-tab-list">
```

The problem I am having is that my scss file is appending to the class name, which I do not want to stop except for 1 specific class:

```
.contact-details-page {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {
        &__tabs {
            .mat-tab-header {
                display: none !important;
            }
        }
    }
```

This will render something like .mat-tab-header[ng_content_xsd]

in react module css, I would do this:

```
.contact-details-page global:(.mat-tab-header) {
  ...
}
```

but I cant figure out how to do this in Angulat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular, CSS is encapsulated (adding `_ngcontent-xxx`). So a component cannot change the style of its sub component.

If what you are trying to do is changing style of an Angular Material component, you have to do it in your root file `styles.scss` (or a sub file imported by `styles.scss`). This is the only place where style is not encapsulated. So code you write there must be written in a generic way (to be reusable).